# It's not possible to edit a SonarQube rule because it's not displayed

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

We just updated SonarQube from 4.2 to 4.5.4 but we have a problem with the following Java rule:

```
Key : squid:MethodCyclomaticComplexity
Name: Methods should not be too complex
```

The rule is used in the analysis and several complexity issues are correctly found, but it's not possible to edit the rule (to change the Threshold value, for example) because the rule is not displayed in the web interface:

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Log in SonarQube
2. Click on Rules
3. Search for "MethodCyclomaticComplexity"
4. Click on MethodCyclomaticComplexity rule found at the left side of
   the window

Result: Nothing appears at the right side of the window!!!

Please, could someone help to resolve this?

Comment: Just to be sure: have you copied the content of "data/es" when doing the upgrade from 4.2 to 4.5.4? If yes, then you shoudn't have. And to fix this issue, you just have to stop SQ, delete the "data/es" folder and restart SQ.

Comment: Touché! At the beginning we started from scratch, without the data/es directory, but after we run several acceptance tests, we upgraded the production DB using the same area (with the data/es already there). We followed your suggestion: stopped SonarQube, removed data/es, started SonarQube and the problem is solved! Fabrice, thanks a lot for your prompt response.

Comment: I've added an answer so that you can officially validate it for other users to benefit from it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "data/es" folder should not be copied when doing a SonarQube upgrade (see the ["upgrading" guide](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading)).

So to solve your issue:

1. Stop SQ
2. Drop the "data/es" folder
3. Restart SQ, et voilà!